# Does luarocks have a shrinkwrap or lockdown option?

Tags: dependency-management, luarocks

Other package managers have a lock down option. For example, on a dev machine you might have certain packages and certain versions. The goal would be to install those same packages and versions on a staging or production environment. Sometimes this is called shrinkwrap or lockdown.

Does luarocks have something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of LuaRocks 2.4.2, this is unfortunately not available as a single command.

But here is a sequence of operations that produces a similar effect.

In the dev machine:

```
mkdir packages
cd packages
luarocks list --porcelain | awk '{print $1}' | uniq > packages.txt
for p in $(cat packages.txt); do luarocks pack $p; done
luarocks-admin make-manifest .
cd ..
tar czvpf packages.tar.gz packages
```

Copy `packages.tar.gz` to the target machine then run:

```
tar zxvpf packages.tar.gz
luarocks --only-server=./packages install foo
```

This will install package "foo" picking dependencies and sub-dependencies only from the `packages/` directory (and not from the network), so all dependencies are guaranteed to be the ones you packaged in the dev machine.

Comment: Thanks. I actually like these simple steps over a "single, magical command". Those commands hide too much.